# angular function dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Where do i place the common `handleError` and `handleSuccess` functions.

These are common functions that will be used by every service. where is the best place to put these functions. Should i put theses as global functions and inject them as dependency.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp.Group')
        .service('GroupService', function ($http, $q, $location, Environment) {



            // I transform the error response, unwrapping the application dta from
            // the API response payload.
            function handleError(response) {

                // The API response from the server should be returned in a
                // nomralized format. However, if the request was not handled by the
                // server (or what not handles properly - ex. server error), then we
                // may have to normalize it on our end, as best we can.
                if (!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
                    return ($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
                }

                // Otherwise, use expected error message.
                return ($q.reject(response.data.message));

            }


            // I transform the successful response, unwrapping the application data
            // from the API response payload.
            function handleSuccess(response) {
                return (response.data);
            }

            this.remove = function (id) {
                var request = $http({
                        method: "delete",
                        url: '/group/' + id
                    });
                return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
            };
        });
}());
```

Comment: i am afraid your question is not clear.. please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how we do it:

We use the $httpProvider to intercept the responses and deal with each code on their own.  We made a service to handle this functionality.

Our app config looks like this:

```
appModule.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$provide',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $provide) {
    // Http interceptor to handle session timeouts and basic errors
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(['httpHandlersSrv', function (httpHandlersSrv) {
        return function (promise) { return promise.then(httpHandlersSrv.success, httpHandlersSrv.error); };
    }]);
    routeProvider = $routeProvider;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
]);
```

This is what our $httpHandlersSrv looks like where we handle errors.  Notice we just pass the successful responses along without doing anything:

```
angular.module('appModule').factory('httpHandlersSrv', ['$q', '$location', '$rootScope', 'toaster', '$window', function ($q, $location, $rootScope, toaster, $window) {
return {
    success: function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    error: function (response) {
        switch (response.status) {
            case 0:
                //Do something when we don't get a response back
                break;
            case 401:
                //Do something when we get an authorization error
                break;
            case 400:
               //Do something for other errors
                break;
            case 500:
               //Do something when we get a server error
                break;
            default:
                //Do something with other error codes
                break;
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: shouldn't i add httpHandlersSrv as a dependency in first one

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that.  The service we created is specifically for handling the responses and does nothing else.

Comment: also what will be my ajax call now

Comment: You should look at using the $resource factory to make your ajax calls.  If you go that route (which is the correct route), you don't need to do anything special.  All responses from all ajax calls with be handled via the above service.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource